# Inequality concerning integral w.r.t. Hölder functions

Tags: real-analysis, inequalities

I didn't get any reaction on that question on Math.stackexchange. 
So I hope to get a hint from the experts.

I have to prove the following inequality. 
Let  $\nu$  be a function on $[0,1]$ with one discontinuity point $x^{*}$. Furthermore, we set $\Delta\nu_{x}:=\nu_{x}-\underset{t\uparrow x}{\text{lim }}\nu_{t}$. We do the following assumptions. For $w_{x}:=\nu_{x}-\Delta\nu_{x^{*}}\mathbb{I}_{\{x\geq x^{*}\}}$ it holds that $\underset{x,y}{\text{sup}}\left|w_{x}-w_{y}\right|\leq L\delta^{\alpha}$ with $\alpha\in\left(0,1\right)$ and the sup is taken over all $x,y$ s.t. $\left|x-y\right|<\delta$. Finally we assume $\Delta\nu_{x^{*}}>b$.
Then I have to prove:
$$ \frac{1}{z}\left|\int_{x^{*}-z}^{x^{*}}\nu_{s}ds-\int_{x^{*}}^{x^{*}+z}\nu_{s}ds\right|\geq b-2Lz^{\alpha}. $$
I think it should be a straightforward application of the reverse triangle inequality, but I am not really able to work it out rigorously.

Comment: You have a strange definition of $w_x$: it should really be $\nu_x-\Delta\nu_{x^*}I_{\{x\ge x^*\}}$ where $I_E$ is the indicator function of the set $E$. That's probably what is confusing you. Voting to close.

Comment: This is not my own creation. If you have editor rights, feel free to correct my post. 
Nevertheless, could you give me a hint, how to tackle this task?
Edit: I have corrected the definition of $w$.

Comment: The inequality is trivial, but I suspect you confused yourself (and others, over at MSE) with the not very reader friendly notation (for starters, why do you write $f_x$ for what the rest of the world calls $f(x)$). Your function $\nu=w+b\theta(x-x^*)$ has a Holder continuous part and a jump at $x^*$, and now just look at the contributions these two parts make to your integrals.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I am a statistician, and that's why I am used to apply that notation. 
I am very sorry for that.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Would you like to write down an answer on MSE? As I think that this question isn't really research level. 
Here is the link to the MSE question: 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2338000/reverse-triangle-inequality

Then I think one could close/delete this question in order to keep MO "clean".

Comment: @Xarrus: I've answered over at MSE.